# Can we update any fhir resource on the basis of patient id?

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi, hapi-fhir

I am trying to update Encounter resource on the basis of patient id but it is only creating one new record of Encounter rather than updating the existing one. But if i try to update Encounter on the basis of identifier i.e. unique value representing Encounter resource then it is able to update it.

Why is that? Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One patient will potentially have many (even hundreds) of encounters.  Updates are always driven by the record of the resource itself - every resource (Patient, Encounter, Observation, CarePlan, etc.) has an 'id' element that represents the identifier of that resource on that particular server - sort of like a primary key.  Updates are performed by making a RESTful PUT of the new record to a URL that includes that same identifier.

I.e. an update of an Encounter MUST always be performed with a URL of the form:

`PUT [somebaseurl]/Encounter/[serverEncounterId]`

The patient associated with the encounter will be referenced from within the Encounter object in the body of the RESTful call, but does not appear in the URL.

Comment: but at the time of update i only know the patient id not that unique identifier then how will it solve my problem? Right now i only have one encounter resource associated with that patient. So it should clearly identify the that resource and update it but it is simply creating a new record.

Comment: You have to query before you can perform an update.  Otherwise, you can't know what data you're going to be overwriting.

Comment: This question triggers something...that I've been "preachin" in all these dev days and forums.  The patient-search (or maybe more preferably, patient-match) is probably the key prerequisite for all this stuff.    https://www.hl7.org/fhir/patient-operation-match.html       Note, there is a patient-match OPERATION which is slightly different from patient-search.  But yeah, besides my soapbox...Lloyd is correct.  You have to do some "searching" for the encounter if you don't have access to teh enncounter(id, aka surrogate key).

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, some FHIR servers will allow a 'conditional update':

`PUT [somebaseurl]/Encounter?search_key=search_value&...`

You will need to add search parameters that filter all Encounters and result in a unique one, which will then be updated. Since, as Lloyd also indicated, a Patient can have multiple associated Encounters, the Patient id is not a suitable parameter for the conditional update. Your Encounter's identifier was unique enough, so that update succeeded.